# Do race conditions exist in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was writing a controller and ended up with a situation where a user's action changed state on `$scope` as did a `$timeout` running at potentially the same time. Is this something to be aware of or is it not a problem in AngularJS? Here's a simplification of the code:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) {

 $scope.counter = 0;

 $timeout( function incrementor() {
    $scope.counter += 1;
    $timeout(incrementor, 100);
 }, 100 )


 // Call when user clicks a button
 $scope.onClick = function() {
    $scope.counter += 1;
 }

}
```

I understand that there is only a single thread running, but what operations are atomic?

Comment: You should be keeping track of the timeout as a variable, and clearing the timeout if it's been set previously. That's just a general rule of thumb with timeouts invoked by user behavior. Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't you be using setInterval here?

Comment: setInterval does not execute the body in the context of $scope.$apply, $timeout does.

Comment: There's also $interval which calls scope.$apply().

Answer (score -1):

As you said, Javascript is single threaded so there's no risk of mutating the same object at the same time. Your timeout function and your onClick function will never execute exactly at the same time (although it might seem like it).

What you could do in a situation like this is add a safe guard in your timer, something like this:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.counter = 0;

    var lastIntervalCounter = $scope.counter;
    $interval(function incrementor() {
        if (lastIntervalCounter == $scope.counter) {
            // Only perform this if the counter hasn't been modified
            // since the last time incrementor was called
            $scope.counter += 1;
        }
        lastIntervalCounter = $scope.counter;
    }, 100);
}
```